# Python data data conversion

Tags: python, pandas

Please help with the below request:

need to clean up below df to df_1: 'SKU' has multiple required data, and this column needs to be exploded to multiple rows

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,'NaN','abj','1/1/2021'],
               [2,'[{"Result":"00018"},{"Result":"00065"}]','abj','1/1/2021'],
               [3,'','abj','1/1/2021']],
                 columns = ['ID','SKU','NOTES','Date'])
```

df

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame([['1','','abj'],
                 ['2','00018','abj'],
                 ['2','00065','abj'],
                 ['3','','abj']],
                 columns = ['ID','SKU','NOTES'])
```

df_1

Comment: Are your lists of dictionaries an actual list or string (as you have it in your example)?

Comment: the data is coming from csv as one row for SKU column.. that would be string

Answer (score 0):

To convert the SKU values from `str` to `dictionary`, I used `json` module as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

df = pd.DataFrame([
    [1, 'NaN', 'abj', '1/1/2021'],
    [2, '[{"Result":"00018"},{"Result":"00065"}]', 'abj', '1/1/2021'],
    [3, '', 'abj', '1/1/2021']],
    columns=['ID', 'SKU', 'NOTES', 'Date']
)

new_df = {
    'ID': [],
    'SKU': [],
    'NOTES': []
}

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if (row['SKU']) in ('NaN', ''): # if row['SKU'] format is not what you want 
        continue

    results = json.loads(row['SKU'])
    for res in results:
        new_df['ID'].append(row['ID'])
        new_df['SKU'].append(res['Result'])
        new_df['NOTES'].append(row['NOTES'])

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(new_df)
print(df_1)

#  ID    SKU NOTES
#0   2  00018   abj
#1   2  00065   abj
```

For another way of converting `str` to `dictionary`, you can see: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-convert-string-dictionary-to-dictionary/

Comment: i get this error, on passing a .csv file. TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not int

Comment: @spartan123 This code itself must works, but if you want to get `df` from .csv file, then you need to check if the `df` is really printed as you explained in the questions. Or, it would be helpful if you upload your full code (at least a part of reading csv file)

Comment: the current df is from .csv file. SKU_ID column is object type, might consists of NaN and [{"Result":"00028"},{"Result":"00063"}]. Please refer to the modified question. Thanks

Comment: @spartan123 I added `if` statement inside the `for` loop in my code to deal with the exceptional cases, such as 'NaN', ''. You can deal with any other values in the `if` statement. I also edited the sample data and tested.

Answer (score 0):

If all records are following the same pattern, this should clean it for you.

Beware that the code below is modifying *df*.

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import numpy as np

def clean_SKU(x):
    if pd.isna(x) or x == "" or x == "NaN":
        return x
    else:
        return [ i['Result']  for i in  json.loads(x)]

df.SKU = df.SKU.apply(lambda x : clean_SKU(x))

df.explode('SKU')
```

Comment: if my first row in 'SKU' is null or NaN or ' ', then error is: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: Please refer to the modified question. Thanks

Comment: You may consider filter out those values. However, I modified the code above so it won't return an error.

Comment: also you can extend the *clean_SKU* function's *if* statement with further exceptions, if null, NaN, "NaN", "" are not covering your need.